# Token replace for commerce products in rules

Tags: commerce, rules, tokens

I'm trying to create a rule for automatically generating a commerce products titles from all the values of products fields.
After each values I need to add suffix like cm, W, kg, mm e.g.
In order to make the title beautiful, for example "Product Name 10cm 150W 35kg" instead of "Product Name cm W kg", I need to check for empty tokens, but this check for empty tokens is my problem.

```
$power = "[current-product:field_power]";
if (!empty($power)) {echo "$power". "W ";}
echo strlen($power); //test for what happens
```

Second line all time print "W" with or without value. (Empty check not work) The third line all time print "29" (same as token name length). As a result I can't check $power var for emptiness.
For node fields I success with token replace:

```
$brand = token_replace('[node:field-brand]', array('node' => $node));
if ($brand != "") {echo $brand . " ";}
```

But token replace not work for products variants.
How correctly use token replace for products field of how to check products field for emptiness without token replace?

Export of rule:

```
{ "rules_change_product_variants_titles_after_node_save" : {
    "LABEL" : "Change product variants titles after node save",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "php", "rules" ],
    "ON" : {
      "node_insert--product" : { "bundle" : "product" },
      "node_update--product" : { "bundle" : "product" }
    },
    "DO" : [
      { "LOOP" : {
          "USING" : { "list" : [ "node:field-product-variants" ] },
          "ITEM" : { "current_product" : "Current product variant" },
          "DO" : [
            { "data_set" : {
                "data" : [ "current-product:title" ],
                "value" : "[node:title] \r\n\u003C?php\r\n    $brand = token_replace(\u0027[node:field-brand]\u0027, array(\u0027node\u0027 =\u003E $node));\r\n    $type = token_replace(\u0027[node:field-type]\u0027, array(\u0027node\u0027 =\u003E $node));\r\n\r\n\/\/add space after brand and type of product display\r\n    if ($brand != \u0022\u0022) {echo $brand . \u0022 \u0022;}\r\n    if ($type != \u0022\u0022) {echo $type . \u0022 \u0022;}\r\n\r\n    $x = \u0022[current-product:field-width]\u0022;\r\n    $y = \u0022[current-product:field-height]\u0022;\r\n    $z = \u0022[current-product:field-length]\u0022;\r\n    $diameter = \u0022[current-product:field_diameter]\u0022;\r\n    $power = \u0022[current-product:field_power]\u0022;\r\n    $weight = \u0022[current-product:field-weight]\u0022;\r\n\r\n\/\/ make product size like 10x20x15cm, not like 10cmxcm15cm\r\nif (empty($x)) {\r\n  if (empty($y)) {\r\n    if (empty($z)) {}\r\n    else {echo $z . \u0022cm \u0022;}\r\n  }\r\n  else {\r\n    if (empty($z)) {echo $y . \u0022cm \u0022;}\r\n    else {echo $y . \u0022x\u0022 . $z . \u0022cm \u0022;}\r\n  }\r\n}\r\nelse {\r\n  if (empty($y)) {\r\n    if (empty($z)) {echo $x . \u0022cm \u0022;}\r\n    else {echo $x . \u0022x\u0022 . $z . \u0022cm \u0022;}\r\n  }\r\n  else {\r\n    if (empty($z)) {echo $x . \u0022x\u0022 . $y . \u0022cm \u0022;}\r\n    else {echo $x . \u0022x\u0022 . $y . \u0022x\u0022 . $z . \u0022cm \u0022;}\r\n  }\r\n}\r\n\r\n\/\/ I can\u0027t check this data for empty value\r\necho $power . \u0022W \u0022;\r\necho $weight . \u0022kg \u0022;\r\necho $diameter . \u0022cm \u0022;\r\n?\u003E"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Add rule export to question